# Mysql creating double insert when missing html image

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have found an error in my code that somehow having html code with a image with no url causes my mysql query to insert twice. Is there any logic to this or is there something else wrong in my code? Please keep in mind hat I am still learning php and mysql.

HTML code

```
<td width="70"><img src="" height="70" width="70"></td>
```

MYSQL code

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database`.`user_inventory` (`user_id`, `item_id`, `status`) VALUES (1, 1, 'locked')");
```

Comment: The code block didnt work for me here is all of the html code  &lt;td width="70"&gt;&lt;img src="" height="70" width="70"&gt;&lt;/td&gt;

Comment: You'll need to show a lot more code than that, particularly around the insert. I can't see how the HTML is related though

Comment: I removed all other code except the insert code and the database connection code then narrowed it down to the html line that when commented out or with a url added for the image it stops double inserting. Also thanks for fixing my code block on the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image with no `src` tries to load the current page as the image (the same way how `<a href="">` links back to the current page). If the MySQL query is triggered every time the page is loaded that's why you're seeng it happen twice. There's not really a reason to have an empty `src` anyway.

Comment: sigh turn around to answer a question across the room and miss out by a second or two :\

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me. The only reason that I had an empty tag in there was because the page is still being built. I guess for now I will put a temp or broken image inside of the tag. You learn something new every day I guess.

Comment: Well spotted. What's concerning here is that the PHP code is inserting on a GET request

Comment: @Shikoru Change your code to only run the insert on a POST request

Answer (score 0):

When you leave off the src attribute or do not specify it (`src=""`) your browser will default the value to the current page sending a second request. This would likely be the source of your secondary insert.